# click on a cell change the value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, cells

I can not achieve to do what looks like an easy process...
I would like to give a value ("Hello") to a cell (named "ClInfo") in sheet named "Hardware" by a click on a cell (C47) in sheet named "1".

I tried this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C47")) Is Nothing Then
        .range("ClInfo").value = "hello"
    End If
End If
```

What should I do to make it works?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code could look like the following, it looks like you're just missing the Worksheet object:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C47")) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Hardware").Range("ClInfo").Value = "hello"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Make sure you're placing this as the VBA for your sheet named `1`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it does work now. For no reason, I tried that before but did not achieve to make it works, probably a misspell something... thx again!

Comment: Still needs some help... The solution above fully worked!
But I have now another issue. The target range needs to be cell and merged cells... I know... merge cell are really to avoid, but cannot do any other way for this dashboard. I tried everything that I saw (mergearea, cell(1)... but nothing seems to work. Any idea? Btw, thx @Jonno, I just noticed you are the one helping for both question I posted :)

Comment: No one got an idea for that?

Comment: @AdriendeHarlez Sorry, I didn't see this before. What exactly are you struggling with? Copying the value into a merged cell?

Comment: Hi @Jonno. I'd like to target merged cell. So in (your) screenshot above, let'say the target would be :
range("C47:E47") instead of range("C47")
because C:E are merged. When I do that, nothing happens. Like if the script does not notice I select those merged cells... What can I do ? thx!!

Comment: maybe you did not see this one @Jonno ?
Don't want to bother you though...

Comment: @AdriendeHarlez Agh sorry... I think merged cells just use the reference of the first cell. So in this case, if you've merged C47, D47 and E47, you just reference C47 and it changes the contents of the entire merged cell. Have you tried just using the address of the first cell in the merge?